# FECHAS ME LAS TOMA COMO UN CARACTER EN EXCEL

Tags: vb.net, excel, aplicación-web

este es el problema, yo estoy haciendo un programa en vb.net para cargar información en un excel, perfecto me carga toda la información en el mismo, pero yo al ejecutar los filtros veo que en los datos tipo fecha, no me los esta tomando como Fecha si no como un caracter, no hay una posibilidad de que en vb.net,  me dejo la data tal cual como el dato que es. Yo utilizo un datatable para cargarlo la información al excel, ya que el número de columnas puede ser n.

Muchas gracias y quedo atento a una respuesta pronta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el fichero de importación? es para ver más de cerca el problema.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar usar esto:

```
Dim fechatexto = "16/01/2021"
dim fechaDate as DateTime
        
        DateTime.TryParseExact(fechatexto, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, fechaDate)
```

Referencia:
[DateTime.TryParseExac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Hola Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, pues implemente lo que me dijiste pero ahora me sale con hora, no hay una manera de quitarle la hora y solo me quede en fecha¿?